# In an Angular Unit Test, how can I mock an entire component, instead of just a class?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to unit test a component that is using a subcomponent. I need to mock the subcomponent because the subcomponent uses CanvasJS to display plots, which doesn't work well with Jest Unit Tests.

Right now, this is being used in my spec file as seen below:

```
import { SubComponent } from '../shared/components/sub/sub.component';
import { SubComponentMock } from '../shared/mocks/component/SubComponentMocks';
...

  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: PageComponent,
    declarations: [ViewComponent],
    imports: [],
    providers: [
      { provide: SubComponent, useClass: SubComponentMock },
    ],
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    spectator = createComponent();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(spectator.component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

My SubComponentMocks file contains a class `SubComponentMock` which has functions that are in SubComponent. I am getting the following error:

`Cannot find module 'canvasjs' from 'sub.component.ts'`

Shouldn't the mock cause the test to not try to find that module at all? It shouldn't be doing anything in sub.component.ts, it should only be accessing SubComponentMocks. Is there a way for the whole component to be mocked so the test doesn't try to find the canvasjs module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add mock subcomponent in your spec like this :-

```
 @Component({
    selector:'sub'
    })
    class MockComponent{
    mockProperty <----- which being used
    }
```

and in create component do this :-

```
const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: PageComponent,
    declarations: [ViewComponent,MockComponent],
    imports: [],
    providers: [],
  });
```

Comment: What would go at "mockProperty"? Is this just an empty class?

Comment: No I indicated mock property if your component have any property which could be value for  nested child component ,otherwise you don't need to mention any property .It should work fine.

Comment: @Matt123 let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I still have the same error. Either I have no idea what I'm doing, or canvasjs just makes unit testing impossible. @Aditya

Answer (score -1):

I am familiar with Karma and Jasmine but I assume Jest behaves the same in this regard.

In your use case, I would take advantage of the `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`. This basically tells Angular, if you see an element in the HTML that you don't recognize, don't worry about it.

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
......
const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: PageComponent,
    declarations: [ViewComponent],
    imports: [],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  });
```

The way you are mocking the component right now is how you would mock a service.

Also, Aditya's way might work too but I find `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` to be better (less work if you don't care about the child components in your unit tests).

Also, look into `overrideComponent` and `overrideModule` but this maybe only if you're using Angular's methodology for testing.

**===== edit ==========**

Never mind, it seems like you're using `ngneat` for testing. I would leverage `componentMocks` property then, not `schema`.